# Why does the Titan not descend attached to a surface-attached "leash"?

Tags: submarines

Wouldnt such a design prevent loss of contact?

Comment: Your leash would not make any difference for a catastrophic failure.

Comment: The weight of the umbilical.  It operates in international waters to avoid safety features.

Comment: It wouldn't prevent loss of contact only minimize the possibility; a fault could develop with the cable.

Comment: You're probably underestimating just how long a cable it would have to be. The Titanic wreck is 12,500 ft or over *2 miles* deep.  The Titan sub wasn't lost because it couldn't contact the surface; it was lost because its owners were careless fools who disregarded the warnings of engineers and deployed it to a depth far beyond what it was built for.

Comment: One could reasonably ask "why didn't they" questions about assorted well-engineered constructions. Asking this about badly-engineered ones? In case of good ideas you can simply assume "because they were morons"

Comment: Because it would cost more. The CEO would rule it out based on that alone, before the fact that it would be heavy, nor practical, nor effective, nor feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Titanic is 12,000 feet underwater. So a 12,000 foot umbilical cable,
Using say....  a 2 inch thick galvanized steel wire rope would weigh 7.8 pounds per foot, would weigh 47 tons.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but it greatly increases the chances that the umbilical cable will get foul-snagged on a piece of the wreckage and become stuck.

Comment: Do you think that's the reason there isn't one? At least in such a situation they would still know where it was and perhaps even be able to feed down more oxygen

Comment: I do think that's the reason it has no umbilical. Omitting that creates a balancing act between underwater mobility, safety, and submerged duration. In this case, the balancing act failed.